# Insert line break for UILabel text when a specific character is found

Tags: ios, swift, string, text, uilabel

I have a UILabel that dynamically gets updated every time I click a button, the data will be fetched from firebase and displayed on the uilabel.I am able to display the text as shown below. I would like to insert a line break when a specific delimiter(say '.' PERIOD) is encountered in the text. I have looked into many solutions about UIlabel line break but couldn't find one what exactly I am looking for, every solution deals with static text that we provide in the storyboard itself. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.
[image])

[image: UILabel text content]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the attributed text property of UILabel. Try to find and replace the character with html line break and then assign this text to the UILabel attributed text.

You can replace string by

```swift
let str = "This is the string to be replaced by a new string"
let replacedStr = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "string", with: "str")
```

Answer (score 4):

Created an outlet for the label and have taken a string which has three sentences separated by ".". The content in the image attached will be this string. Try using replacingOccurences() function as given below.

```
@IBOutlet weak var trialLabel: UILabel!

var string = "This is a trial text.Let us jump to a new line when the full stop is encountered.Hope it helps."

string = string.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: ".\n")
trialLabel.text = string
```

Check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412937-replacingoccurrences for further reference. Happy Coding!!

Comment: My pleasure...Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

use below code 
// HTML Tag Remove Method

```
extension String{

    func removeHtmlFromString(inPutString: String) -> String{

        return inPutString.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: ".\n", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
    }
}


   let str = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500."

  let postDiscription = str!.removeHtmlFromString(inPutString: str!)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a \n in the text string to where you want to create a line break.